# Merge rows with same ID

Tags: sql, merge, rows

I have the following table:

```
ID | variant_name   | variant_color
1  | BMW 7-series   | Black
2  | Volvo C60      | Gray
1  | BMW 3-series   | White
3  | Subaru Forester| Orange
2  | Volvo XC90     | Green
```

How can I query to gain this result:

```
ID | variant_name_1 | variant_color_1| variant_name_2 | variant_color_2|
1  | BMW 7-series   | Black          | BMW 3-series   | White          |
2  | Volvo C60      | Gray           | Volvo XC90     | Green          |
3  | Subaru Forester| Orange         |                |                |
```

Each ID has a maximum number of variants of 2.

Thanks!

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: Hi Tai Ngo, what have you tried so far? do you have any partial result you're not happy with? it may help to see where you are. Most of the time people on StackOverflow want to be sure that people asking question have put some effort before posting it here...

Comment: which variant goes into "variant_name_1" ?

Comment: Hey everyone, thank you for the support! I've figured out my problem from the suggestions by fa06 and Yogesh Sharma. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll work in sql server/posgresql/oracle - use row_number()

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7540/10424

```
 select id, max(case when rn=1 then variant_name end) as variant_name1,max(case when rn=1 then variant_color end) as variant_color1,
    max(case when rn=2 then variant_name end) as variant_name2,max(case when rn=2 then variant_color end) as variant_color2
    from
    (
    select id, variant_name, variant_color, row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as rn
    from tablename)a
    group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to do conditional aggregation :

```
select id, max(case when seq = 1 then variant_name end) as variant_name_1,
           max(case when seq = 1 then variant_color end) as variant_color_1,
           max(case when seq = 2 then variant_name end) as variant_name_2,
           max(case when seq = 2 then variant_color end) as variant_color_2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by variant_color) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try left joining with itself:

```
select c1.id,
       c1.variant_name as variant_name_1,
       c1.variant_color as variant_color_1,
       c2.variant_name as variant_name_2,
       c2.variant_color as variant_color_2
  from cars c1
  left join cars c2
    on c1.id = c2.id
   and c1.seq <> c2.seq
 group by c1.id
```